# Paragraphs and list when using /// comments after each line code

Tags: doxygen

I'm currently documenting a C code which is not from me.
Either than commenting the code, and then making blocks for Doxygen documentation, I prefer to put comments after each line of code (with ///) in order to implement directly everything in Doxygen.

So far it works very well but I'm not able to generate lists and paragraphs. It seams that list and paragraph are reinitialized each time I start a new comment on next line with ///

Is there something I am missing ?

[EDIT] : an exemple :

So this works perfectly fine, if I put it before my function :

```
/**
* 1. Title 1. \n
*    Description 1. \n
*    More description \n
*    - Subtitle1. \n
*    - Subtitle2. \n
*      Description of subtitle2 \n
* 2. Title 2. \n
*    Description 2.
*/
```

But this don't work at all, if I put it INSIDE my function :

```
Some code     /// 1. Title 1. \n
other code    ///    Description 1. \n
x=x           ///    More description \n
y=x           ///    - Subtitle1. \n
code          ///    - Subtitle2. \n
code          ///      Description of subtitle2 \n
code          /// 2. Title 2. \n
code          ///    Description 2.
```

It behaves like if each line was a new comment block.

Thank you,

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give an example of where you have problems with lists and paragraphs and what you have tried at those places?

Comment: I've edited my frist post. It's only when I add comments after code. When I have a complete block of comment, it works fine

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have here internal function documentation, have a look at the command `\internal` and the setting `INTERNAL_DOCS` also the way you write will not work at all as each time you have a new code statement  you will start a new block. Probably you should also read-up on `///` and `//<`